# Biased probability

Tags: probability, statistics

Assume that players Terry, Tom, and Jay have biased coins with probabilities of 0.9, 0.6, and 0.4 of landing heads respectively. If the outcome of one player differs from the outcomes of the other two players, then the game ends and this player wins. Otherwise, they start over again. What is the probability that Terry wins the game?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A game ends in a given round when it is not the case that all three flipped the same result.  This happens with probability $1-\underbrace{0.9\cdot 0.6\cdot 0.4}_{HHH} - \underbrace{0.1\cdot 0.4\cdot 0.6}_{TTT} = 0.76$

Terry is the victor in the first round happens with probability $\underbrace{0.9\cdot 0.4\cdot 0.6}_{HTT} + \underbrace{0.1\cdot 0.6\cdot 0.4}_{THH} = 0.24$

Now... notice that if we ever have a round which does not end the game, we continue to be in effectively the same situation as before and so rounds which don't end the game can be effectively ignored and conditioned away from.  Our probability we are after then is the same as the probability that Terry wins in the first round given that the first round a winner was declared, and this happens to be the ratio of the previously found values:

$$\dfrac{0.24}{0.76} \approx 0.31579$$

Answer (score -1):

Let **P(T)** be the probability that Terry wins on a given round. For Terry to win, he must flip heads while both Tom and Jay flip tails.

The probability of Terry flipping heads is **0.9**, and the probability of Tom and Jay flipping tails is **(1 - 0.6) = 0.4** for Tom and **(1 - 0.4) = 0.6** for Jay.

**P(T) = (0.9) * (0.4) * (0.6) = 0.216** (probability that Terry wins in a single round)

Now, to find the probability that Terry wins the game, we need to consider all possible cases. The game can end in 3 ways:

1.Terry wins on the first round **(P(T))**.

2.Tom wins on the first round (P(T')) and Terry wins on the second round (P(T)), which is **(1 - P(T)) * P(T)**.

3.Jay wins on the first round (P(J)) and Terry wins on the second round (P(T)), which is **(1 - P(T)) * (1 - P(T)) * P(T)**.

So, the total probability that Terry wins the game is:

P(Terry wins) = P(T) + (1 - P(T)) * P(T) + (1 - P(T)) * (1 - P(T)) * P(T)

P(Terry wins) = 0.216 + (1 - 0.216) * 0.216 + (1 - 0.216) * (1 - 0.216) * 0.216

**P(Terry wins) ≈ 0.523182976**

Final answer : approximately **52.32%**.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Comment: Besides, the answer is wrong.